# Extract data from objects nested at different depths in a huge JSON file

Tags: json, bash, shell, loops

I used following code to grab data from a huge json format file.

```
_ITEM_L1=`cat json.list | jq .item[].length | wc -l`
for (( i=0;i<$_ITEM_L1;i++ ));
do
    _ITEM_L2=`cat json.list | jq .item[$i].item[].length | wc -l`
    for (( j=0;j<$_ITEM_L2;j++ ));
    do
        _API_NAME=`cat json.list | jq .item[$i].item[$j].name`
        _API_URL=`cat json.list | jq .item[$i].item[$j].request.url.raw`
        echo $_API_NAME
        echo $_API_URL;
    done;
done
```

At First I think its only 2 level, but when I run the script I found its more than 2 level, it could be 3 or 4 even 5 or more.
So my question is how to know how many levels in a json file before I start the iterate?

```
item0
    |
    item0
         |
         item0
              name:
              url:
         item1
              name:
              url:
         item2
              name:
              url:
    item1
         |
         item0
              |
              item0
                   name:
                   url:
              item1
                   name:
                   url:
         item1
              |
              item0
                   name:
                   url:
              item1
                   name:
                   url:
              item2
                   name:
                   url:
item1
     |
     item0
          name:
          url:
     item1
          name:
          url:
     item2
          name:
          url:
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Show your input and expected output.

Comment: You should spend some time learning [tag:jq]

Comment: jq's streaming mode is much more appropriate here.

Comment: BTW, a diagram of your input is pretty much useless -- it can't be used to test an answer. Provide an actual *sample*.

Comment: For example, your ASCII-art tree shows `name:` and `url:` next to each other (and I wrote my answer in accordance with that specification), but your sample code says that `url` should really be `request.url.raw`.

Answer (score 0):

A better design wouldn't *require* you to know how many levels of nesting depth there are in your file, and **definitely** wouldn't be calling `jq` over and over in a loop! (`jq` is a full-fledged programming language -- it's able to loop on its own, and it's much more efficient to process the whole file in just one jq invocation rather than calling it over and over with different filters).

---

Let's start with a concrete example input:

```
{
  "item0": {
    "item0a": {
      "item0aA": {
        "name": "foo",
        "url": "bar"
      },
      "item0aB": {
        "name": "baz",
        "url": "qux"
      }
    }
  },
  "item1": {
    "name": "qux",
    "url": "quux"
  }
}
```

To convert this into a flattened name/url set of pairs, one could use:

```
jq -r '.. | objects | select(.name? != null) | [ .name, .url ] | @tsv'
```

which will emit as output:

```
foo bar
baz qux
qux quux
```

...which you can trivially iterate over in bash:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r name url; do
  echo "Read name $name and url $url"
done < <(jq -r '.. | objects | select(.name? != null) | [ .name, .url ] | @tsv' <json.list)
```

Breaking down how this works:

- `..` is jq's recursive descent operator.
- `objects` ignores things which aren't objects.
- `.name? != null` filters only for objects which have names. (One could similarly filter for only objects that have URLs the same way).
- `@tsv` puts output in tab-separated value form.
- `IFS=$'\t' read -r name url` reads a line of input into the variables `name` and `url`, with a tab separating them.